# Hibernate errors after migration to Widlfy 28.0.1/Hibernate 6.21

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, wildfly

I'm migrating Wildfly from 26.0.1 to 28.0.1 and am hitting some Hibernate errors.

I have an abstract class with an @ElementCollection

```
@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@CollectionTable(name = "RELATED_IDS", joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "FK_ID"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "FK_VER")})
@AttributeOverride(name = "id", column = @Column(name = "RELATED_ID"))
private Set<ID> content = new HashSet<>();
```

The errors only occurs when deleting from an implementing entity. Selecting seems to work fine.

```
em.createQuery("delete from MyEntity t where t.pk.id in (:deleteIds)")
            .setParameter("deleteIds", deleteIds).executeUpdate();
```

The following errors occur when the query is being executed

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.hibernate.sql.ast.tree.from.TableReference.getIdentificationVariable()" because the return value of "org.hibernate.sql.ast.tree.from.TableGroup.resolveTableReference(String)" is null
    at org.hibernate@6.2.1.Final//org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.internal.MappingModelCreationHelper.lambda$buildColumnReferenceExpression$9(MappingModelCreationHelper.java:1555)
    at org.hibernate@6.2.1.Final//org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.internal.SelectableMappingsImpl.forEachSelectable(SelectableMappingsImpl.java:159)
    at org.hibernate@6.2.1.Final//org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.internal.AbstractEmbeddableMapping.forEachSelectable(AbstractEmbeddableMapping.java:523)
    at org.hibernate@6.2.1.Final//org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.EmbeddableValuedModelPart.forEachSelectable(EmbeddableValuedModelPart.java:136)
    at org.hibernate@6.2.1.Final//org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.ModelPart.forEachSelectable(ModelPart.java:130)
    at org.hibernate@6.2.1.Final//org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.ValuedModelPart.forEachSelectable(ValuedModelPart.java:52)
    at org.hibernate@6.2.1.Final//org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.internal.MappingModelCreationHelper.buildColumnReferenceExpression(MappingModelCreationHelper.java:1547)
    at org.hibernate@6.2.1.Final//org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.SimpleDeleteQueryPlan.lambda$executeUpdate$0(SimpleDeleteQueryPlan.java:162)
    at org.hibernate@6.2.1.Final//org.hibernate.query.sqm.mutation.internal.SqmMutationStrategyHelper.cleanUpCollectionTable(SqmMutationStrategyHelper.java:164)
    at org.hibernate@6.2.1.Final//org.hibernate.query.sqm.mutation.internal.SqmMutationStrategyHelper.lambda$cleanUpCollectionTables$2(SqmMutationStrategyHelper.java:86)
    at org.hibernate@6.2.1.Final//org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.internal.ImmutableAttributeMappingList.forEach(ImmutableAttributeMappingList.java:49)
    at org.hibernate@6.2.1.Final//org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.forEachAttributeMapping(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4518)
    at org.hibernate@6.2.1.Final//org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.visitSubTypeAttributeMappings(AbstractEntityPersister.java:5741)
    at org.hibernate@6.2.1.Final//org.hibernate.query.sqm.mutation.internal.SqmMutationStrategyHelper.cleanUpCollectionTables(SqmMutationStrategyHelper.java:83)
    at org.hibernate@6.2.1.Final//org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.SimpleDeleteQueryPlan.executeUpdate(SimpleDeleteQueryPlan.java:136)
    at org.hibernate@6.2.1.Final//org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.QuerySqmImpl.doExecuteUpdate(QuerySqmImpl.java:739)
    at org.hibernate@6.2.1.Final//org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.QuerySqmImpl.executeUpdate(QuerySqmImpl.java:709)
```

The error does not occur, when pulling the @ElementCollection up to the concrete entities, but this construct is used multiple times throughout our code, i can't change them all.

Edit: The abstact classes are annotated with @Entity. When is remove this, the delete query successfully executed, but i can not map with @JoinTable anymore

Comment: I have removed the `@Entity` annotation where possible and split `@JoinTable` to the concrete classes, because joining to the abstract class also caused the same error. Now everything works...